# Обязательно ли писать export react компонента на отдельной строке?

Tags: reactjs

Часто вижу вот такой вариант экспорта функции в React, экспорт пишется отдельно, на другой строке:

```
function HelloWorld (props) {
return (<h1>Привет, Мир!!! Меня зовут <b>{props.name}</b></h1>);
}
export default HelloWorld;
```

В этом есть какой то глубинный смысл или можно экспортировать сразу же при объявлении функции:

```
export default function HelloWorld (props) {
return (<h1>Привет, Мир!!! Меня зовут <b>{props.name}</b></h1>)
}
```

Comment: Все равно как писать... Но я использую "экспорты" в самом конце модуля, т.к. в нем могут быть и другие "элементы", которые не будут экспортированы. А так, глянул в конец модуля - а там перечень всего того что будет экспортировать модуль... ;)

Comment: Дело вкуса и договоренностей команды